# Flutter/Dart: What is the difference between a library and a flile?

Tags: flutter, dart, private

When I code, I import my local files via the package... anotation. In flutter, there is no private, protected, public, but instead there is library privacy with the underscore _ . When I import a local file, I can't access private members, therefore, a local file is library, right?

Answer (score -1):

A single file is a library, but you can have multiple files be a library. Have a file that only imports other files in the library to make that the main library file. In a directory, usually the the main file is at the root and in a subdirectory is each part. There are many other ways to do it. I suggest just having all the code for the library in a single file.

Comment: Why oh why should all the code for a library be in a single file?

Comment: Organization, Dart/Flutter "libraries" have a different context than other languages. A package would usually have multiple files. Dart is phasing out multi file libraries. I summed up this article: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fluttering-dart-libraries-and-packages-972edf864ff9

Comment: That is not what that three year old(!) article is saying and it is not what the official documentation is saying either. https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages But each to their own when it comes to opinions.